# Campo many to many en django

Tags: python, django

Tengo este formulario y quiero representar el campo utiles_herramientas que es un many to many como una tabla...

```
class EmpleadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Empleado
        fields = [
            'area',
            'nombre',
            'apellidos',
            'cargo',
            'utiles_herramientas'
        ]
        labels = {
            'area': 'Area Laboral',
            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'apellidos': 'Apellidos',
            'cargo': 'Cargo',
            'utiles_herramientas': 'Útiles y Herramientas'

        }
        widgets = {
            'area': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-1'}),
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-1'}),
            'apellidos': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-1'}),
            'cargo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-1'}),

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(EmpleadoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["utiles_herramientas"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["utiles_herramientas"].queryset = Utile.objects.all()
```

El problema es que cuando pongo {{form.utiles_herramientas}} en el template se me renderiza como una lista, y necesitaria que fuera en una tabla de manera individual.
lo que me sale es esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero algo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, quiza puedas revisar esto: https://github.com/willardmr/DjangoTableSelectMultipleWidget

Comment: no me funciono, o puede ser que no sepa bien como usarlo, puedes echarme una mano con eso???

Comment: @Javier, puedes poner el código de lo que hiciste con el ejemplo que sugirió Diego Avila ?

Comment: no me funciono muy bien, pero la verdad es que no lo eh probado a fondo

Comment: me da un error en el queryset que no tengo idea de que sea